# How to access a json file in an n-tier mvc application VS2015

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, n-tier-architecture

I have a visual studio solution that contains several projects, including a service project (Business logic), and an MVC UI project(Presentation).

Within the service project I have a json file which I need to access in one of the service project classes.

The problem I have is that almost everything I try returns a path to the UI project (Not where the json file is)

Things I have tried:

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "geo.json");
//returns a path contained within UI project

HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/geo.json");
// also returns a path contained within UI project

Environment.CurrentDirectory;
// returns C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express
```

How can I get the path to a json file that is not contained within the UI project?

Comment: What sort of project is the 'service project' ? Is it a class library (a .dll) ?

Comment: It is a class library.

Comment: Your JSON for your class library will eventually end up in your UI's folder structure (likely in the `bin`) when you deploy. You will need right-click the JSON file in your class library, select `Properties` and change the `Copy to Output Directory` to either of the copy options.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I followed the steps above, then accessed the file through the base directory. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the "service project" is a class library, you cannot really do anything relative to the path of the class library.

The class library is turned into a `.dll` file, at compile time, and it is copied into the bin folder of the project that references it (also at compile time).

So when the code in the service project asks where it is running from, it returns the location of the code that references it, because that's where the `.dll` file ends up.

I hope this makes some amount of sense. It would be much easier to explain if I could use hand puppets, but markdown does not currently support the use of funny props.

As Frank mentions in the comment above, you can tell other files in the service project to also be copied into the bin folder, by selecting the file's properties and choosing "Copy to output directory". If you do this to your geo.json file it will end up in the `bin` folder.

Alternatively, inside the MVC app, you could pass the path of the `geo.json` file into the method of the `.dll` as a parameter. That way it is up to the caller to know where the information is stored.

Comment: (Bear in mind I am asking as a Junior Developer)                                          Is there another type of project that I should use to encompass my business logic considering this scenario?

Comment: ok.. trying to put in enough detail to be useful. Let me know any jargon that is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for that, it does make sense now, I've never come across this situation before.  I suppose it might be better to expose the JSON via a webapi rather than continually update/access it in the bin folder?

Comment: When in doubt always do "the simplest thing that could possibly work"